# ordering of eigenvalues for simultaneously diagonalizable matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, hermitian-matrices

Suppose I have two commuting Hermitian matrices $A$ and $B$: $[A,B] = 0$. I can always find a unitary operator $U$ such that simultaneously diagonalize both matrices, i.e.,

\begin{equation}
U^* A U = D_A, \quad U^* B U = D_B,
\end{equation} where $D_A$ and $D_B$ are corresponding diagonal matrices.

My question is: can we always say that the orderings of eigenvalues of $D_A$ and $D_B$ are the same, e.g., eigenvalues of both $D_A$ and $D_B$ are in descending order ($\lambda_{a_1} \geq \cdots \geq \lambda_{a_n}$ and $\lambda_{b_1} \geq \cdots \geq \lambda_{b_n}$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues, then you are asking for $U^*AU=U^*BU$, which implies $A=B$. So in general you can't do what you are asking about.

Comment: I don't think that $A$ and $B$ share the same eigenvalues in the question. They share the same eigenvectors.

Comment: @PC1, but *if* they have the same eigenvalues.... E.g., if $A=\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&-1}$ and $B=\pmatrix{-1&0\cr0&1}$, then.... All it takes is one example to show what OP wants can't be done. At bottom, your answer and mine have much in common.

Answer (score 0):

No, not in general.

Take for example $A$ and $B$ as diagonal matrices. These will always commute but the entries are not in general ordered in the same way. So any change of basis (a [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) in this case) can't sort the entries in descending order for *both* matrices at the same time.